# Javascript self calling function vs <script> tag placed directly after the HTML element

Tags: javascript

Using script tag:

```
<div id="first">
    me is first
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var first = document.getElementById("first");
    console.log(first);
</script>
```

Self-invoking function:

```
<div id="second">
    me is second
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(){
        var second = document.getElementById("second");
        console.log(second);
    })();
</script>
```

What is the difference in usage between self-calling function and `<script>` tag placed after the html element. I've been debugging for finding a difference. But they seems act same. Or is it just about good/bad practice?

Comment: They are virtually idential. The only difference is that in the second case `second` is not polluting the global scope.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The self-executing function creates a new internal scope which contains the `second` variable and prevents it from leaking into the global namespace. The plain `<script>` block's `first` variable, however, will be added into the global scope.

Keep in mind that individual `script` blocks do not have their own scope, they all operate within the same global scope, which is necessary for scripts to interoperate.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between the two examples you've posted is essentially one is storing a variable (var second) within a function and one is not (var first).

In your second example you are assigning the element object to a variable ***inside*** an anonymous, self-invoking function (no name is attributed to it so it's value is never stored, and the following parenthesis attached at the end call that function).

An example of a named variable is...

```
function yourFunctionName () {
  console.log("I'm a function with a name");
}
```

An anonymous function is a function without a name, even though it's assigned to the variable `anon_function` its' still anonymous...

```
var anon_function = function(){
  console.log("I'm anonymous");
}
```

The return value of the above function is stored in the `anon_function` variable.

The trailing parenthesis tell the function to execute straight away as if you were calling a named function.

```
function(){
  console.log("I'm anonymous and self-invoking");
}()
```

Once the function is run and then terminates, variables created inside the function are discarded and the global object remains as it was.

The parenthesis that wrap the entire function are 'recommended' to help programmers distinguish from normal functions:

```
(function(){
  console.log("I'm anonymous, self-invoking and wrapped in parenthesis just for clarity");
})()
```

There is a short pdf article about self-invoking functions [**here**](https://teaching.cs.uml.edu/~heines/91.461/resources/SlideSharePresentations/JavaScriptPatterns-SelfInvocation.pdf) and a good article on anonymous functions [**here**](http://helephant.com/2008/08/23/javascript-anonymous-functions/)

Comment: I tried running the last self-invoking function you listed, where I defined a variable `a = 1;`. Using Firebug in Firefox, I was able to read the value of `a` outside the function.

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, you can maniuplate the variable `first` within the JavaScript console.

In the self-invoking function, `var second` is protected by the function "wrapper", and cannot be modified by an external JavaScript console. This kind of function is known as an **anonymous function**, since it has no name (unlike `function doStuff()`).

Generally, it is better to write code with a self-invoking function, since variables inside the anonymous function will stay within that scope, and not propagate up into the global scope.